# Is there a way to disable usage of specific packages?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm on a team with multiple developers. We're using JUnit5 via [android-junit5](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5) and tests written using the `@Test` annotation from the `org.junit` package as opposed to the `org.junit.jupiter.api` package are excluded from gradle's test reporting. I'd like to, if possible, outright prevent developers from using `org.junit`. Is there a way to do this using gradle? I'd like to achieve this particular solution and not a workaround as there are other instances that we'd like to prevent users from using a given package (`java.time.*` in Java 8 vs [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP))

Thank you

Comment: I'm not a gradle expert, but does this look useful to you? https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-how-to-exclude-some-tests/

Comment: @IanRehwinkel I haven't been able to get that to work. I believe that's just for excluding particular tests from test runs, and not for excluding usage of specific packages throughout the app.

Comment: You could build a custom Lint rule that looks for classes that you would prefer not to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I figured this was the route I'd have to go.

Answer (score 1):

One way of approaching the problem could be to create a Jar that contains only the allowed APIs. You could then upload that jar to an repository and ask developers to use it as a `testCompileOnly` dependency while keeping the original jar as a `testRuntimeOnly` dependency.

This will guarantee that test code cannot access the forbidden classes/packages since it will not see them during compilation.